# Delphi TPngImage memory leak

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks

I have a record, which looks like this:

```
TCell = record
  Marked:     Boolean;
  ToBeMarked: Boolean;
  Image:      TPngImage;
  end;

var Cells: array of array of TCell
```

Cells[n].Image is created during a certain procedure and then stored for later use. Everytime that procedure is called, this array is being cleared.
However, i still have a memory leak report upon closing the program.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, pngimage, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
TCell = record
  Marked:     Boolean;
  ToBeMarked: Boolean;
  Image:      TPngImage;
  end;
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure  TestProcedure1;
    procedure  TestProcedure2(X,Y: Integer);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  Cells: array of array of TCell;
  RI_LengthX: Integer;
  RI_LengthY: Integer;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
TestProcedure1;
end;

procedure TForm1.TestProcedure1;
var X,Y: Integer;
begin
{ Clearing the array before the new cycle }
for X:=0 to High(Cells) do for Y:=0 to High(Cells[X]) do     Cells[X,Y].Image.Free;
SetLength(Cells,0);
{ Creating new array }
RI_LengthX:=10;
RI_LengthY:=10;
SetLength(Cells,RI_LengthX);
for X:=0 to High(Cells) do SetLength(Cells[X],RI_LengthY);
{ Calling the procedure that creates image for every cell }
for X:=0 to RI_LengthX-1 do for Y:=0 to RI_LengthY-1 do     TestProcedure2(X,Y);
end;

procedure TForm1.TestProcedure2(X,Y: Integer);
var BaseBMP: TBitmap;
begin
{ Dynamic creation of an image }
BaseBMP:=TBitmap.Create;
BaseBMP.Width:=25;
BaseBMP.Height:=25;
{ Saving image inside a record }
Cells[X,Y].Image:=TPngImage.Create; // Commenting these lines
Cells[X,Y].Image.Assign(BaseBMP);   // prevents the leak
BaseBMP.Free;
end;

initialization
ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown:=True;

end.`
```

[image]

Is there a way of avoiding this leak?

Comment: Please show a [mcve]

Comment: Changed the clearing procedure according to Loghman advice and provided a bare minimum of a needed code. The leak still occures.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] instead of a *"bare minimum of needed code"*, whatever that is.

Comment: This is trivial to answer with [mcve] please provide it

Comment: That's exactly it - the code, that causes the leak without the unnecessary details, that have nothing to do with the problem. The provided code is the core of the troublesome module.

Comment: @Robert - Please start a new project, paste the code in this answer to it and try to compile. The details that you find unnecessary prevents us to be able to reproduce your problem. Please read the page that has been linked thrice to understand what it means.

Comment: @Robert - I duplicated your problem. The answer you've already got is accurate in what you must do to free the images. You also need to free the images before the program ends/when you're done with them.

Comment: @Robert, do you still need help with this?

Comment: It's pretty far from minimal. Anyway, you don't destroy the objects that you create. So they are leaked. Pretty mundane. Accept the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

before use `SetLength(Cells,0);` you must do the following code

```
  for i := 0 to High(Cells) do
    Cells[i].Image.Free;
```